# A ZENY Electric guitar

Tags: electric-guitar

I got this guitar, and the amplifier only has the volume, treble, bass, and a overdrive button. What would be a good configuration for a nice clean rock sound.

Comment: not sure this question has an answer that won't just be opinion. use your ears and fiddle around until you find one you like. find a sound on an album and try to recreate it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no right or wrong when it comes to getting a certain sound, but here are a few tips for getting a clean tone:

-don't push in the Overdrive button

-the Treble and Bass are meant for fine tuning the sound. Neither of these knobs alone will have much effect on whether the tone is clean or distorted.

-use the volume on your GUITAR to control how much signal is going into the amp. Keep the volume lower to get a cleaner sound.

-turning the volume up on the amp will usually create a more overdriven sound. You will have to play around with the amp and guitar volumes to find the settings that create the cleanest sound with the most volume.